# How to convert list of PreparedStatements to addbatch and execute at once

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8, prepared-statement, resultset

I have an Insert query where the values are changing dynamically but the table remains the same. I am trying to set the values for those fields using getObject setObject. Once setted when i tried to use addBatch(). The thing is since the preparedStatement Query is varying dynamically for each time and so the previously added data into the batch is not maintaining and only the last record is getting updated into the DB. I also tried committing each time, but thats taking long time if suppose large number of data is been there. So i tried adding all the preparedStatements into a List but i don't know how to add these list into a Batch and execute them all at once also I need to collect the record whichever is failing while executing.

```
rs = first.executeQuery() /// this query willl fetch data from one table that need to be inserted into another DB
List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData() // getting metadata of the resultset
String tablename = metadata.getTableName(1);
List<PreparedStatemnt> list = new ArrayList<>();
while(rs.next()){
for(int i=0;i<= metadata.getColumnCount();i++)
columns.add(metadata.getColumnName(i));
String Query = "Insert into " + tablename + "(" + columns.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ") + ") values (" + columns.stream().map(c -> "?").collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) +")";

rs2 = second.prepareStatment(query);
for(int i=0;i<column.size();i++) rs2.setObject(i, rs.getObject(columns.get(i-1)));
rs2.addBatch();  /// this does not maintain the batch history for each itertation and only holds the last.
list.add(rs2) //
```

not sure on how to execute batch on this list
inserting after each query might me timeconsuming i guess. Kindly help me with an efficient work around.

Answer (score 0):

Here a little snippet code to help you if i understand correctly

you just need to create

```
    // Create a List of PreparedStatements.
List<PreparedStatement> preparedStatements = new ArrayList<>();

// Create your PreparedStatements and add them to the list.
PreparedStatement ps1 = //your query 1
preparedStatements.add(ps1); //add to the list

PreparedStatement ps2 = //your query 2

preparedStatements.add(ps2); //add to the list

// Execute the batch.
for (PreparedStatement ps : preparedStatements) {
    ps.addBatch();
    
}

preparedStatements.get(0).executeBatch();

// then close connection for each statement
for (PreparedStatement ps : preparedStatements) {
    ps.close();
}
```

Comment: will the ps.executeBatch work?
ps will not be accessible outside the forloop?

Comment: need to be inside the for loop

Comment: Then that will be similar to executing the insert query for each time the way the addBatch() and executeBatch() will work at the same time

Comment: since you already addBatch you can do preparedStatements.get(0).executeBatch() ill update the code think it will trigger everything from the list not sure need to try

Comment: if i remember correctly because all PreparedStatements in the batch have the same batch size and parameters, so we can execute the batch on any of them

Comment: Tried this all. This will only add the first element from the list. 
I think these were the suggestions given by chatgpt and i tried this all nothing works as i expect

Comment: then you cannot escape if both prepareStaement has different batch size need individual call

Comment: rules from document is same batch size and parameter you can execute in single batch execution if not then you have to individual call it

Comment: Parameters in the sense does that mean values un the insert statement, if so each insert may have different values not the same at all time

Comment: it mean number of parameter if query has 3 parameters that same doesnt matter what value you pass

Answer (score 0):

You must first realize how *JDBC batch insert* works with a *static* tables **than** you may add the *extension* for dynamic varying of the table name and the column list.

Note that a *batch insert* has no *list of `prepareStatement`* only one `prepareStatement` is used.

**Example**

(pseudocode)

```
String SEL_STMT = "select id, col1,col2 from tab1"
String INS_STMT = "insert into tab2(id, col1,col2) values(?,?,?)"
 
def batchSize = 1000

def stmt = con.prepareStatement(SEL_STMT)

def stmtIns = con2.prepareStatement(INS_STMT) 

 

 def i = 0
 rs = stmt.executeQuery()
 
 while(rs.next())
  {
    stmtIns.setLong(1,rs.getLong(1))
    stmtIns.setString(2,rs.getString(2))
    stmtIns.setTimestamp(3,rs.getTimestamp(3))
    stmtIns.addBatch();
    i += 1
     
    if (i == batchSize) {
        def insRec = stmtIns.executeBatch();
        i = 0
        }
     
  }
 rs.close()
 stmt.close()

// process the last batch
def insRec = stmtIns.executeBatch();

stmtIns.close()
con2.commit()
```

You are reading in a loop the *cursor* date, copy each column value in the `insert` statement (with getXXX and setXXX) and add it to the batch (`addBatch`).

When the batch size is reached you call `executeBatch`  - this will perform *one* roundtrip to the Db and inster teh whole batch of records.

At the end of the loop you must process the last remaing rows (e.g. with batch size = 10 and 104 rows the last 4 rows).

**Dynamics**

Now, when this is clear you may approach the dynamic aspect of the table names and columns list.

The string `INS_STMT` is created based in the metadata of the cursor.

The part `stmtIns.setLong(1,rs.getLong(1))` is performed in a loop for each column  using `set/getObject`